# the final image result changed if i run as a regular test VS run test with coverage (in intellij)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

i'm trying to build ray tracing system
the problem is when i run test of Image with Junit Tester
the result is completely different from when i do with Run-With-Coverage.

i have no idea why it happens and what to do next..

the code is absolutely THE SAME.

regular test

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/crKMK.jpg)

with Coverage

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsLo5.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we could have a look at?

Comment: If you're absolutely sure that the code is the same, then the configuration is not. I would look for system properties that are set/unset depending on how you launch the tests.

Comment: @SlawomirChodnicki where can i find those configuration?

Comment: In your test, you could dump out the contents of `System.getProperties()`, to see if there are any differences. Maybe there's differences in class-path or differences in configuration properties that your program or one of your libraries uses.